# No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_up" - When I uncomment :registerable and :recoverable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I also receive this error in the browser;

```
/Users/DylanRichards/Sites/Sites/dylanrichards/app/models/user.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ',' devise :database_authenticatable, registerable:, :recoverable, ^
```

How can I fix this? This site is my personal blog. I've opted to use Devise for authentication.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, registerable:, :recoverable,
          :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

routes.rb

```
Dylanrichards::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :quotes

  resources :photos

  devise_for :users do
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
end




end
```

Comment: I have added this comment into answer section to be clear and will remove comment from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **:** before **registerable:** and omit from end